# Is there a way to connect to a REPL without comint?

Tags: comint, repl

The performance of comint is not good when handling outputs of some REPL. Is there a way to connect to some REPL outside Emacs and let result display there, like in a terminal/browser/something else?

(I also tried to eval Python code in vscode, their REPL 'running inside the editor' is handling outputs much more efficiently. Maybe they use something like comint in `vscode` or maybe not.)

Answer (score 1):

There is `start-process`, which internally calls `make-process`.

start-process is a compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.

(start-process NAME BUFFER PROGRAM &rest PROGRAM-ARGS)

Start a program in a subprocess.  Return the process object for it.
NAME is name for process.  It is modified if necessary to make it unique.
BUFFER is the buffer (or buffer name) to associate with the process.

---

WRT large output python-mode.el provides commands like py-execute-block-fast:

(py-execute-block-fast &optional SHELL DEDICATED SWITCH BEG END FILE)

Process block at point by a Python interpreter.

Output buffer not in comint-mode, displays "Fast"  by default.